# Using if condition in CMD

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, conditional-statements

EDIT: I have solved my problem based on suggestions from npocmaka and magoo. Now that i understand it is indentation that caused this, can you guys please suggest how i make my code cleaner in future?

Here's my bat file:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    rem set lang pre-requisites
    rem Purpose can be 'test' or 'deploy'
    SET purpose="test"
    SET lang="English-India"
    SET lang_code="EnIn"

    rem if purpose is test then the folder will be EnInP101M2Tsub, if purpose is deploy then EnInP101M2DFull
    if "%purpose%"=="test"( SET folder=="%lang_code%P101M2Tsub" )
    else if "%purpose%"=="deploy"( SET folder=="%lang_code%P101M2DFull" )

    rem set required paths here
    SET audio="C:\Users\Administrator\..path..\%lang%\%purpose%\BGM\M2\%folder%\*.wav"
    SET source="C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Matt_Trial\..path..\%lang%\%purpose%\BGM\M2"
    SET target="C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Matt_Trial\..path..\%lang%\%purpose%\BGM\M3\*"

    rem copying the data
    xcopy  %source% %target% /e /i /h
    rem copying audio files into the other folders
    for /d %%a in (%target%) do copy %audio% "%%a"

    rem renaming M3 folders
    cd %target%
    for /d %%a in (*) do (
      set "p=%%a"
      set "fp=!p:~0,8!" & set "tp=!p:~10!"
      ren %%a !fp!M3!tp!
    )
```

** For your Understanding **
I have 2 folders in my parent folder (M1,M2,M3).
Step 1: I am copying contents in M2 to a new folder M3.
Step 2: I need to copy contents of a folder under M2 which has my audio into all the folders in M3.
Step 3: I rename the folders under M3.

I hope I made myself clear.
I have to figure out the audio path based on the set variables. I need help with the if condition part. As of now I keep getting The system cannot find the file specified. Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few errors.

`SET` will INCLUDE <kbd>"</kbd> after the <kbd>=</kbd> EXCEPT if you are using `SET "var=data" which is used to ensure that trailing spaces on the line are not included in the data assigned.

Any character after the <kbd>=</kbd> will be included (some need to be 'escaped' if they have a special meaning to batch, so `set var==data` will include the second <kbd>=</kbd> in the data assigned.

You haven't fallen into the spaces-in-variables trap - the syntax `set var =data` will set a variable named var<kbd>space</kbd> not var.

There must be a space (strictly a separator, I believe) between the second operand of an `IF` statement and <kbd>(</kbd> (if used)

Similarly, the ELSE clause must be <kbd>)</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>else<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> - all on the same line. This sequence of characters cannot be broken.

In your `IF`, you are using `"%purpose%"` Since `purpose` us set to `"test"` then this will be evaluated as `""test""`, which is likely to be confusing, hence don't include <kbd>"</kbd> in your data assigned unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Points noted :)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me once again. I would dearly appreciate any more suggestions on making the code cleaner for future. It would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
  @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    rem set lang pre-requisites
    rem Purpose can be 'test' or 'deploy'
    SET purpose="test"
    SET lang="English-India"
    SET lang_code="EnIn"

    rem if purpose is test then the folder will be EnInP101M2Tsub, if purpose is deploy then EnInP101M2DFull
    if "%purpose%"=="test"( SET folder=="%lang_code%P101M2Tsub" )
    else if "%purpose%"=="deploy"( SET folder=="%lang_code%P101M2DFull" )
```

Rather should look like (as you have only two options..)

```
   @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    rem set lang pre-requisites
    rem Purpose can be 'test' or 'deploy'
    SET "purpose=test"
    SET "lang=English-India"
    SET "lang_code=EnIn"

      rem if purpose is test then the folder will be EnInP101M2Tsub, if purpose is deploy then EnInP101M2DFull
       if "%purpose%"=="test" (  
        SET "folder=%lang_code%P101M2Tsub" 
       ) 

       if "%purpose%"=="deploy" ( 
         SET "folder=%lang_code%P101M2DFull"
       )

       echo %folder%
       endlocal
```

You cannot start a line with `else` and set does not work properly with double `=` . And your comparisons are not correct as you have a quotes in variable values.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply. I actually tried that. But when i run my bat file, an error occurs saying Syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks,
Turns out the problem indeed is indentation!!

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me once again. I would dearly appreciate any more suggestions on making the code cleaner for future. It would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 50 rep yet so have to comment via answer instead.

When i run into issues with my batch files I find it helpful to `REM` the `@ECHO OFF` line.

Then create a short-cut to the batch file and change the 'Target' field to pipe the output to a text file.

So, if your batch is at C:\test\mybatch.bat  then create a shortcut to the batch in C:\test\

Next right-click the shortcut and select 'Properties'.
Under the 'Shortcut' tab, add the following to the end of the text in the target field..
`>>output.txt`

Run the shortcut which will save all the commands and errors to the `output.txt` file where you can see what is causing the issue, such as a variable not being set.

Comment: "I don't have 50 rep yet so have to comment via answer instead."
You have a better rep than me :)

Comment: Hey! That sounds like an interesting way to troubleshoot. Will implement this when i run into trouble. Thanks again. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use round parenthesis. Remember that `if .... (` and `) else (` are inextricably linked to a single line (Each one has to be in a single line).

```bash
...
if "%purpose%"=="test" (
    SET "folder=%lang_code%P101M2Tsub"
) else (
    if "%purpose%"=="deploy" (
        SET "folder=%lang_code%P101M2DFull" 
    )
)
...
```

Note:
I found extra issues in your set assignment:

1. Extra equal.
2. Double quotes.

> Suppose Lang_code is equals to -EN-

```bash
SET folder=="%lang_code%P101M2Tsub"
Echo [%folder%]
```

> It shows

```bash
[="-EN-P101M2Tsub"]
```

The correct way should be:

```bash
SET "folder=%lang_code%P101M2Tsub"
Echo [%folder%]
```

> It shows

```bash
[-EN-P101M2Tsub]
```